# .class expected and illegal expression

Tags: java

can any of you help me with this program I'm doing? I'm trying to compile it but can't figure out what's happening with it. There are two java files, I'm going to send just the main one which is the problematic one (until now). It's a simple program to calculate the monthly profit of a company.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthExe{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "Inform the current year..." );
        public int curYear = input.nextInt();
        public int catNum;
        String control = "n";
        while ( control = "n" ){
            System.out.println( "Inform the current month..." );
            int curMonth = input.nextInt();
            Month month = new Month( curMonth );
            month.monthMessage( curMonth );
            String control = input.next();
        }
        System.out.println( "Inform the number of arts..." );
        curArts = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Inform the number of categories from the cheapest to the most expensive one..." );
        catNum = input.nextInt();
        curVals = new double[ catNum ];
        for ( int i = 0; int = catNum; i++ ){
            System.out.println( "Inform the price of the category" + ( i + 1 ) );
            curVals[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        Month month = new Month( curYear, curArts, curVals );
        for ( int j = 1; int = curArts; j++ ){
            for ( int k = 1; int = curVals.length; k++ ){
                System.out.println( "Inform the amount of units sold for product " + j + " and category " + k );
                int curAmount = input.nextInt();
                month.setProfit( curAmount, k );
                month.setTotalProfit( month.getTotalProfit() );
            }
        }
        month.finalMessage();
        System.out.println( "Thank you for using this software!" );
    }
}
```

Trying to compile the above program returns me these 5 errors... can someone explain what they mean? Thank you in advance!

MonthExe.java:7: error: illegal start of expression
                public int curYear = input.nextInt();

MonthExe.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
                public int catNum;

MonthExe.java:22: error: '.class' expected
                for ( int i = 0; int < catNum; i++ ){

MonthExe.java:27: error: '.class' expected
                for ( int j = 1; int <= curArts; j++ ){

MonthExe.java:28: error: '.class' expected
                        for ( int k = 1; int <= curVals.length; k++ ){

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare `public` variables inside a method. Remove the keyword `public`.

Comment: Thank you!! I forgot about that!

Answer (score 2):

For errors #1 and 2, remove the `public` keyword, you can't scope vars inside a method (more [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html))

For errors #3, 4, and 5, the second expression in a for loop declaration needs to evaluate to a boolean. For #3 `int = catNum` should be something like this: `i < catNum`. Same for #4 and 5. (more info on for loops [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html))

Comment: I changed the three of them to boolean operators like <= and < and the error persists.

Comment: Did you change `int` to `i`, `j` and `k`?